# Como mover Linux a otro disco

Tags: linux

Tengo un disco duro de 1TB con 3 particiones (1 para mis documentos, otros para mis multimedias y el ultimo con sistema operativo linux), el caso que quiero mover el sistema operativo linux al otro disco (SSD) ya instalado en la maquina, pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo

> Ya intente Con `Acronis True Image` que es para hacer esas gestiones de discos pero me clona todo el disco literal con sus particiones (osea tres particiones) de lo cual solo quiero la particion donde se encuentra linux

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque  no es de programación

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el comando `dd`

sería algo así como:

`dd if=/dev/sdAB of=/dev/sdC`

Siendo AB la unidad y subunidad de tu partición origen, y C la unidad de tu disco destino.

Para saber las unidades de disco existentes en tu sistema puedes usar el comando `lsblk`

Answer (score 0):

No es necesario utilizar ningún software privativo, puedes hacerlo sin problemas con **Gparted**.

Vé al disco de origen, selecciona la partición, da un clic dercho y, en la barra de herramientas, dirígete a **Partición** > **Copiar**, ve al disco de destino y, otra vez en la barra de herramientas, dirígete a **Partición** > **Pegar**.

Aplica los cambios y debería ser todo.